# How to define variables via macros

Tags: c, macros, variable-declaration

I want to define macro which declare and initialize variables. More precisely I want that macro `MYVARS(x,y)` will be repalced to

```
int myvar=x; 
int myvarr=y;
```

I write

```
#define MYVARS(x,y) int myvar=x;##\n##int myvarr=y;
```

But after preprocessing I see that MY_VAR(50,60) will be replaced to `int myvar=50\ nint myvarr=60;`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have the variable declarations on separate lines.  Just forego the `\n` altogether and do:

```
#define MYVARS(x,y) int myvar=x; int myvarr=y;
```

or, even better:

```
#define MYVARS(x,y) int myvar=x, myvarr=y;
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there exist a way to define macro with line separator?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:: `#define MYVARS(x,y) int myvar=x,myvarr=y;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
#define MYVARS(x,y) int myvar=x;\
                    int myvarr=y;
```